# Disabling Indexing in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

A users computer is being bogged down during the workday by repeated indexing.  I want to disable this at the cost of slower searches.  I disabled the service entirely in services.msc.  I right clicked the C drive and unchecked "index this drive".  Furthermore I went into the control panel and manually unchecked each location that could be indexed. My question, how is this machine *still* indexing, and what? Will malware disguise itself as indexing? There are network drives attached and she uses Outlook, if this helps.  So

**How do I permanently disable indexing in Windows XP?**

Comment: How do you know it is still indexing?

Comment: LifeH20 - I know it's still indexing because the little magnifying glass icon appears in the task bar, the computer grinds to a crawl, and mousing over the icon reads "indexing"

Comment: why -1 a comment that is marked to be deleted? kind of pointless no?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the service and unchecking from properties should work. See this link for help with pictures http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-File-Indexing-on-Windows-XP

Try this as well

> 1.Double-click **My Computer**, point to **Explorer Bar** on the **View** menu, and then click **Search**.
>   2.Click **Change preferences**, and then click **Without Indexing Service**.
>   3.Click **No, do not enable Indexing Service**, and then click **OK**.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899869